Wiped Windows C drive the wrong way, installed Ubuntu 20.04, WiFi stopped working
My computer was originally running Windows 11 and, idiot me, I went into recovery mode and manually deleted everything in my C: drive. I tried to reinstall Windows using my installation media, but it seemed to be corrupted and did not work. It turns out I had a spare Ubuntu 20.04 installation media, and I tried to use Ubuntu to make a new Windows installation media. This did not work, as the drive did not seem to register as bootable. I basically gave up and was going to try Ubuntu for a while, when my WiFi started to go really slow. I did a speedtest and it said I had poor internet. I knew my WiFi was really fast and I ran the test on my phone. It said my connection was perfect. I also experienced a strange bug where I clicked restart while logged in and it logged me out. I tried to restart again and it didn't work. Then it said something about an automatic upgrade. I let it go for a while, but when it rebooted, the problem was still there. Any help either for reinstalling Windows (which I think might fix it, but I'm not sure) or just fixing the WiFi problem would be much appreciated.

This is not the place for Windows help, but for wifi help, please tell us what wifi card you have, what driver you are using. Add into your original posting, not in comments. Also include (cut and paste text) the first page of output in a terminal of the command nmcli dev wifi

One Ubuntu question per post, please.
